# calculate with an array and print the outcome with the input of a user

Tags: php, html, arrays, math

so am trying to make a calculator that calculates units when you convert them.
now I can't get the answer to show up of what the answer is and which units have been converted and the math behind it under the answer

the code

```
<?php
    $units = [
        'kilometer'  => 0.001, 'hectometer' => 0.01, 'decameter' => 0.1, 'meter' => 1, 'decimeter' => 10,
        'centimeter' => 100, 'millimeter' => 1000, 'micrometer' => 1000000, 'nanometer' => 1000000000, 'mile' => 0.00062,
        'yard'       => 1.09361, 'foot' => 3.28084, 'inch' => 39.3700787, 'nauticalmile' => 0.0005399568,
    ];

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $input = $_POST['input'];
        $meters = $_POST['meters'];
        $convert = $_POST['convert'];
        $output = $units[$meters] * $input * $units[$convert];
        echo($output);

    }

    ?>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="input" placeholder="inputnumber">
        <select name="meters">
            <option value="kilometer">kilometer</option>
            <option value="hectometer">hectometer</option>
            <option value="decameter">decameter</option>
            <option value="meter">meter</option>
            <option value="decimeter">decimeter</option>
            <option value="centimeter">centimeter</option>
            <option value="millimeter">millimeter</option>
            <option value="micrometer">micrometer</option>
            <option value="nanometer">nanometer</option>
            <option value="mile">mile</option>
            <option value="yard">yard</option>
            <option value="foot">foot</option>
            <option value="inch">inch</option>
            <option value="nauticalmile">nauticalmile</option>
        </select>
        <select name="convert">
            <option value="10">kilometer</option>
            <option value="1">hectometer</option>
            <option value="0.01">decameter</option>
            <option value="0.001">meter</option>
            <option value="0.0001">decimeter</option>
            <option value="0.00001">centimeter</option>
            <option value="0.000001">millimeter</option>
            <option value="0.0000001">micrometer</option>
            <option value="0.000000001">nanometer</option>
            <option value="0.62137">mile</option>
            <option value="1.09361">yard</option>
            <option value="3.28084">foot</option>
            <option value="39.3700787">inch</option>
            <option value="0.0005399568">nauticalmile</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to `echo($output);` below the form? Or any of the POST values?

Comment: @brombeer yes echo output that's the biggest thing that needs to be done

Comment: Move your `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) ...` block below your form (make sure you start with `<?php` again), echo whatever you need there

Comment: @brombeer that gives me the value but I still can't figure out why I can't get the outcome of for example if I convert 1 kilometer to hectometer that Should be 10 and it's not doing that I just get 1 which is the value of the array which it Should not be

Comment: Then probably your calculation is wrong. Make sure  `$units[$convert]` will actually yield something, there is no `$units['0.01']`. Use "verbose" values for your `convert` input like in your `meters` input. Or just use `$convert` in your formula instead of `$units[$convert]`